# Manipular 2 arquivos json com Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, classificação

Tenho 2 json com a seguinte estrutura e gostaria de colocá-los na mesma ordem atravens do id. É somente um exemplo os 2 json originalmente tem mais de 1000 linhas porem seguem essa mesma estrutura.

```
{
   "data":{
      "json_1":[
         {
            "id":123,
            "name":"Lucas"
         },
         {
            "id":145,
            "name":"Estevam"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

```
{
   "data":{
      "json_2":[
         {
            "id":145,
            "name":"Estevam"
         },
         {
            "id":123,
            "name":"Lucas"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Como o json 2 deve ficar:

```
{
   "data":{
      "json_2":[
         {
            "id":123,
            "name":"Lucas"
         },
         {
            "id":145,
            "name":"Estevam"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Você quer organizar por ordem de ID ou só quer organizar esse caso especifico mesmo?

Comment: coloque um exemplo do resultado esperado pq não ficou claro

Comment: @LucasMódolo Por ID, como eu disse na minha edição de agora esses 2 json são somente um exemplo, o original tem + 1000 linhas porém seguem a mesma estrutura. Espero que com um exemplo colocado fique melhor de entender.

Comment: @RicardoPontual Coloquei.

Comment: @LucasEstevam Respondido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o método [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

**Exemplo:**

```js
let json = {
   "data":{
      "json_2":[
         {
            "id":145,
            "name":"Estevam"
         },
         {
            "id":123,
            "name":"Lucas"
         }
      ]
   }
}

json.data.json_2.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id)

console.log(json)
```

**Sort** é um método que organiza arrays de acordo com um método de comparação. No caso do código a cima, o método de comparação é essa função dentro do método.

O Sort verifica o indice atual e o indice depois, sendo eles o `a` e o `b`. A função pega o valor `a` e `b` e retorna a diferença entre eles. Se for um valor positivo, significa que `b` é maior que `a`, então `b` é movido para um índice anterior a `a`.